# Covariance structure in lme - AR(1)

Tags: r, nlme, random-effects

My response variable is Yijk corresponding to the `recovery` time of

- `patient` i (i=1,...,I)
- with `treatment` j (j=1,...,J)
- and measured at `time` k (k=1,...,K)

I would like to fit the following model:[Model equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRz4N.jpg), where:

- μ is a global fixed intercept
- αj is a fixed effect for the treatment
- bik is a random effect with the following covariance structure. Denote bi the K-dimensional vector of effect for the patient i, then its variance-covariance matrix would have the following AR(1) structure. 
  [Variance covariance matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3uwR.jpg)
- uijk is the usual error term with variance σ²

Consider the following line of command:

```
lme(recovery ~ treatment, method="REML", random=~1|patient, correlation=corAR1,form=~time|patient,data=data)
```

Several questions:

1. What does this `correlation` argument correspond to? The structure of covariance of what? Is that the var-cov matrix which I defined as R?
2. Does the line actually do what I would like to?
3. If not, what does it do?
4. If not, is there a way to do what I would like to?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question appears to ask about interpreting commands in R. This makes it off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a command `lme`, I will assume that is meant to be `nlme` because a) `lme` isn't an R command in any package that I know of or that R could find and b) correlation isn't an option in `lme4`

Second, in the documentation for `nlme` they have this:

> an optional corStruct object describing the within-group correlation
>   structure. See the documentation of corClasses for a description of
>   the available corStruct classes. Defaults to NULL, corresponding to no
>   within-group correlations.

and in `corClasses` it says

> corAR1    autoregressive process of order 1.

So, the answers to your first two questions appears to be "Yes".

Comment: Peter, `lme` is in the package `nlme`; see `?nlme::lme`